# How to salvage logic and data from Yahoo! Pipes?

Tags: export, yahoo-pipes

It is quite sad that Yahoo! [pulls the curtain](http://yahoo.tumblr.com/post/120700756894/q2-2015-progress-report-on-our-product) on the Pipes on August 31, 2015.

How can I salvage the algorithms from the Pipes and ensure continuity of my RSS feeds?

Comment: i'm not familiar with it but your tunblr link links to http://yahoo.tumblr.com/post/120700756894/q2-2015-progress-report-on-our-product  which links to http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/?soc_src=mail&soc_trk=ma which links to http://pipes.yqlblog.net/  which says ................

Comment: it says You can download your Pipe definition by specifying your Pipe-ID (_id) and the output format (_out=json) to the following end-point: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info

For e.g:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ZKJobpaj3BGZOew9G8evXg&_out=json

also mentions Yahoo Developer Forum for Pipes.  https://developer.yahoo.com/forums/#/categories/yahoo-pipes

Comment: @barlop - been there, done that. How do I keep the pipes running? On my own host, in a cloud service, whatever?

Comment: Probably an alternative to yahoo pipes that has an import option, would be easier than your own host.  You could ask on the yahoo pipes developer forum about sucn an option in any alternative.  Or go to websites of the alternatives and ask.. besides asking here.. but i think an alternative to yahoo pipes, with an import option, is the general solution.. just a question of which. As I say, i'm not familiar. You could make enquiries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I didn't manage to replace my Yahoo Pipes, because all solutions require a bunch of effort.

A project which generates python from pipe definitions: https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py

And there is a code which creates node.js modules: https://github.com/neyric/pipes2js

I got the first one at least running and will try to replace my pipes with it asap.

EDIT: In order to download/backup all json definitions of your pipes I wrote this gist: https://gist.github.com/DreamFlasher/58ef69e6ba9972ce2d78

Comment: DreamFlasher, thanks for the tips. Will try these solutions, accept if either is working and report back.

Comment: I am looking forward to your report! If you have difficulties setting up pipe2py, I've documented what worked for me in the issues there. I also have some code to download all your pipe definitions, I will see how I can post that somewhere. github gists maybe?

Comment: Here is the promised gist: https://gist.github.com/DreamFlasher/58ef69e6ba9972ce2d78

Comment: @DeerHunter is it working or do you want to report back? :)

Comment: Know of any options that still work? pipes.yahoo.com is down and I didn't notice it is being shut down until I noticed many of my RSS feeds in Feedly is empty...